# Django Channels, Docker Compose, Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.2', 6379)

Tags: django, python-3.x, redis, docker-compose, django-channels

I am following the Django Channels tutorial available at https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html

I am using docker-compose to build the redis server:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

    command: redis-server --requirepass letmein

    ports:
     - "6379:6379"

    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf


    environment:
     - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master

    networks:
      node_net:
        ipv4_address: 127.0.0.2

networks:
  node_net:
    ipam:
    driver: default
  config:
    - subnet: 127.0.0.0/16
```

When attempting to test the connection with

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
```

I get the error

```
`File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 120, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 180, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 299, in send
    async with self.connection(index) as connection:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 835, in __aenter__
    self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 73, in pop
    conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 175, in create_redis
    loop=loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 113, in create_connection
    timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 339, in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py", line 24, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 794, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 781, in create_connection
    yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 439, in sock_connect
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 469, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.2', 6379)`
```

The advice available at: [Docker [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976480/docker-errno-111-connect-call-failed-127-0-0-1-6379) describes changing `127.0.0.1:6379` to `redis:6379`. However it is unclear where this change should occur:

in my `settings.py` ?

```
`CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.2', 6379)],
        },
    },
}`
```

or in my `docker-compose.yml`? or another place? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `'127.0.0.2'` instead of `'127.0.0.1'` for localhost

Comment: My goal is to access the redis server inside the redis docker container, the address (Within the redis container's IP namespace)  that i have bound for redis is 127.0.0.2. This is defined in my redis.conf. The issue is, the localhost on the django web container, is not the same as the localhost of the redis container. The same applies for 127.0.0.2. I am unsure of how to access the redis address space from the django web container. Happy to elaborate for clarity and thank you for your response :)