# Django Channels, how to set redis docker container ip as host

Tags: django, redis, docker-compose, django-channels

I am attempting to follow the tutorial at  [https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.htm](http://%20https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.htm)

I am using docker-compose to run the redis server needed for Django Channels as opposed to the plain docker command. However i am unsure of how to set the ip address in :

```
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.2', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

to that of the redis container.

i have the following in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
   redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

    command: redis-server --requirepass letmein

    ports:
     - "6379:6379"

    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf


    environment:
     - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master

    networks:
      node_net:
        ipv4_address: 127.0.0.2

networks:
  node_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 127.0.0.0/16
```

When i try and test the connection with:

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
```

i receive the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 120, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 180, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 299, in send
    async with self.connection(index) as connection:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 835, in __aenter__
    self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 73, in pop
    conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 175, in create_redis
    loop=loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 113, in create_connection
    timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 339, in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py", line 24, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 794, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 781, in create_connection
    yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 439, in sock_connect
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 469, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.2', 6379)
```

I understand that the ip address namespaces are different between containers, so how do i access, 127.0.0.2:6379 on the redis container?

The advice available at: [Docker [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976480/docker-errno-111-connect-call-failed-127-0-0-1-6379)

suggests changing `127.0.0.1:6379` to `redis:6379` but that is fairly ambiguous, and changing it directly in `settings.py` i.e:

```
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('redis', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

results in: 
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 120, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 180, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 299, in send
    async with self.connection(index) as connection:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 835, in __aenter__
    self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 73, in pop
    conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 175, in create_redis
    loop=loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 113, in create_connection
    timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 339, in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py", line 24, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 750, in create_connection
    infos = f1.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`
```

So here i am, asking you for help, any suggestions, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you solve this?