# Receiving [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379) using Django via Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis

I'm running Django in a production environment and my websockets will connect but won't send any data. I do however receive `[Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)` as an error. I heard that it's because of my settings.py, but so far I haven't found a solid fix. Here's what I have so far.

### Setup

Procfile:

```
web: daphne API.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker background -v2
```

settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

asgi.py:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': django_asgi_app,
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url('timer', TestConsumer.as_asgi()),
                ]
            )
        )
    ),
    'channel': ChannelNameRouter({
        'background': BackgroundConsumer.as_asgi()
    })
})
```

Log of Heroku Redis server connection:

```
2021-07-03T18:33:56.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-angular-30850 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.43 sample#load-avg-5m=0.34 sample#load-avg-15m=0.285 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15628108kB sample#memory-free=5542160kB sample#memory-cached=5297476kB sample#memory-redis=333688bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
```

Redis Addon for Heroku was added, but I didn't take any further steps to run it. It does however, display that its "Available" in its settings.

### Problem/Logs

The output is a `[Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)` error when signaling the Redis server. Websockets dont seem to do anything other than simply connect.

Logs:

```
ConnectionRefusedError at /API/1/
[Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)
Request Method: PUT
Request URL:    http://example.herokuapp.com/API/1/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py, line 528, in _sock_connect_cb
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.10
```

### What I've tried

1. Changing redis hosts to `"hosts": [("redis", 6379)],`, as mentioned here [Docker [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976480/docker-errno-111-connect-call-failed-127-0-0-1-6379)
2. Changed procfile, didnt work whatsoever
3. Tried to "run" the Redis server on Heroku, as mentioned here https://github.com/django/channels_redis/issues/102 Didn't figure that one out, I think the Redis addon runs automatically

If anyone has any tips I'd appreciate it. I think this is a really simple fix that I'm just not understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you have connected.  Error 111 is "connection refused".  You're sure you have a Redis server running on that same server on port 6379?

Comment: Herokus logs indicate that there IS an active connection to the Redis server, but the call fails for some reason. The logs have been amended in the op.